# How to Add value in existing key value and update the collection in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I am using mongodb with meteor and I want to add the new amount in existing amount value key in mongodb and update the same collection.
Can I do addition in mongodb query directly?
*payment.update({},$add{$set:{amount: amount}});*
something like this so the new amount directly added into pervious amount;

Answer (score 3):

You can use mongo $inc to increment the value like this:

```
payment.update({},{$inc:{amount: amount}});
```

This will increase amount of all doc by amount.

You can also update doc based on the condition like this:

```
payment.update({'_id':docId},{$inc:{amount: amount}});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
db.payments.update({"some":"condition"}, {$inc:{amount:new_amount}})
```

This will add new amount to old amount.